# jQuery problem with each() and prepend function for ul and li elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Add JavaScript + jQuery code that will number the list items after loading the document
by adding the next item number in bold at the beginning;

```
1 Poland
2 Germany
3 Italy
```

My code si below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $('li').prepend(
            each(function(index){
                index++;
               index + ": " + $( this ).text();
            }))
        ;
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Poland</li>
        <li>Germany</li>
        <li>Italy</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Not work. I tried many times without results.

Comment: Please explain clearly

Comment: For starters, you can use an `<ol>` instead, that will put the numbers there with pure HTML. As for your code, you need to switch it around: you need to `prepend` *inside* the `each` loop: https://jsfiddle.net/uhoc9fs2/

Comment: I have to add javascript + jquery code with each() and prepend() function to display unnumbered. In ```<li>``` I must display number of item and item

Comment: What means - `number of item and item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ol in html (ordered list)` or nice to make it using javascript or jquery because some time you may not use `ol and ul` maybe you want to make a counter in a table, I write a simple code for you If you have any question tell me.

```js
// Using For Loop
/*for (let i = 0; i < $("#ul li").length;  i= i + 1 ) {
    $("#ul li").eq(i).prepend("<span class='counter'>" + (i + 1) + "</span> ")
}*/

// Using Each Loop

$( "#ul li" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).prepend("<span class='counter'>" + (index + 1) + "</span> ")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
    <li>Poland</li>
    <li>Germany</li>
    <li>Italy</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand right you, you don't need to use javascript for this.

Please check below,

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  max-width: 350px;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
ul li {
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter);
  color: #fcd000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left:-40px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Poland</li>
  <li>Germany</li>
  <li>Italy</li>
</ul>
```

And more information if you need;

https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/